# BackboneJS: router.navigate is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I am trying to build microstate history with this:

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{"":"home",":slug":"pages"},
    pages:function(slug){alert(slug);},
    home:function(){alert('home');}
}) ;

Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    silent: true
});

$(document).on("click","a",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
    router.navigate($(this).attr('href'),true) ;
});
```

But console says: **"Uncaught TypeError: router.navigate is not a function"**

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate your router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{"":"home",":slug":"pages"},
    pages:function(slug){alert(slug);},
    home:function(){alert('home');}
});

Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    silent: true
});

var router = new AppRouter();
$(document).on("click","a",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
    router.navigate($(this).attr('href'),true) ;
});
```